# Choosing 3 groups out of 10 people

Tags: combinatorics

There are 10 people in the club. I want to make 3 teams out of them. Two of the teams (team A and B) will have 3 good players, and the latter one (team C) will have the 4 remaining students. In how many ways can I choose these teams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends very much on **how many** good players there are. The simplest assumption is that there are exactly $6$.

Imagine first that we will give the teams **labels** A, B, C, maybe t-shirts with these letters on them. Then there are $\dbinom{6}{3}$, that is, $20$ ways to select the people who will wear the A shirts, and now the rest of the division into teams is determined.

However, if we are just thinking about division into **unlabelled** teams, when shirts are removed the division that has say players $1$, $2$, $3$ in Team A, and $4$, $5$, $6$ in Team B is indistinguishable from the division where we have $4$, $5$, $6$ in Team A and $1$, $2$, $3$ in Team B. So there are only $\frac{20}{2}$ ways of dividing our group into unlabelled teams.

Similar reasoning takes care of more complicated cases where there are more than $6$ good players. For example, suppose there are $7$. Then there are $\dbinom{7}{1}$ ways to decide which good player will go to the team of four. For every such way, there are, for *labelled teams*, $\dbinom{6}{3}$ ways to decide who goes to Team A, and we get a total of $\dbinom{7}{1}\dbinom{6}{3}$. For *unlabelled* teams, divide by $2$.

Comment: So, if all players are candidates to be good players, the solution should be $\dbinom{10}{4}\dbinom{6}{3} = 4200$?

Comment: @Helen: If all players *are* good players, and we are dividing into labelled teams, your expression is right. As before, for unlabelled, divide by $2$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

i think:

$(10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8) \cdot (7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5)=151200$

Comment: I would be happy if you add some explanation. It looks like your answer is $10!/7! * 7!/4!$... but why?

Comment: for example: for first Person team A has 10 choise, for second person team A or B have 9 choise, for six person team A or B have 5 choise. and last 4 person for team C.

Comment: I think the order is important in your answer, but it shouldn't be. There are $3!$ choices that make team A from the same 3 people.

Answer (score 0):

Great question;

looks like you are looking for how many combinations have can have dividing $10$ people as  $4$, $3$, and $3$ again;

Very easy to see visually using factorials

$$\frac{10!}{4!3!3!}$$

Expanding out completely:

$$ \frac{10\times9\times8\times7\times6\times5\times4\times3\times2\times1}{4\times3\times2\times1\times3\times2\times1\times3\times2\times1}$$

Canceling first group out:
$$\frac{10\times9\times8\times7\times6\times5}{3\times2\times3\times2}$$

Canceling second group out:
$$\frac{10\times9\times8\times7\times5}{3\times2}$$

Canceling third group out:
$$5\times3\times8\times7\times5 = 4200$$